# Is std::remove_if with lambda predicate and auto element possible?

Tags: c++, stl, lambda, c++11

I'm assuming this is not possible because I got the following error:

```
error C3533: 'auto': a parameter cannot have a type that contains 'auto'
```

Here's a code snippet to reproduce the error:

```
int myInts[] = {1,2,3,3,3,4};
std::vector<int> myVec(myInts, myInts + sizeof(myInts)/sizeof(int));
myVec.erase(
    std::remove_if(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(),
        [](auto i){return i==3;}), // lambda param error
    myVec.end());
```

Now if you were to write this instead everything is fine and it will erase elements with the value of 3:

```
int myInts[] = {1,2,3,3,3,4};
std::vector<int> myVec(myInts, myInts + sizeof(myInts)/sizeof(int));
myVec.erase(
    std::remove_if(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(),
        [](int i){return i==3;}),
    myVec.end());
```

So can you simply not use `auto` as a function parameter as the error suggests?

Is this because the type of `auto` is determined by the *rvalue* which the compiler can't deduce despite it being a predicate of an algorithm executed on a known vector of `int`?

Does anyone know the reason?

Comment: Herb Sutter talked about this recently on Channel 9. http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Herb-Sutter-C-Questions-and-Answers

Comment: That would probably be very interesting if I could make it past 4 seconds without it buffering lol.

Comment: Download links are on the right.

Comment: In C++14, generic lambdas where introduced ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31442974/4566599), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17233649/4566599)) which allow the usage of `auto`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sadly, while this was suggested during the C++0x process, this ultimately never made it in. For simple functors, you may want to use something like Boost.Lambda (perhaps Phoenix v3 when it comes out, too), where the functors generated are polymorphic (and thus you don't need to specify anything):

```
std::remove_if(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(),
    _1 == 3)
```

---

The solution with type inference only:

```
// uses pass-by-reference unlike the question
std::remove_if(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(),
    [](decltype(myVec[0]) i){return i==3;})
```

Comment: Last I heard, Boost.Phoenix v3 is the official replacement for Boost.Lambda (and eventually Boost.Bind), so given that Boost.Lambda has no future it would be better to start with Phoenix v2 (or wait for v3) and ignore Boost.Lambda altogether.

Comment: nifty, we use boost so that's an option but I've been trying to get familiar with C++0x features recently.

Comment: @AJG86 There is no C++0x feature that allows creating polymorphic functors on the fly -- although your particular problem only needs type inference to be solved, not full-on polymorphism

Answer (score 8):

An `auto` is a type inference based on the value you're initialising it to. A parameter isn't initialised to anything at the place it appears in the code.

Comment: I get the same error when defaulting the value of an `auto` parameter in a function so I guess that's not enough but that was kind of expected.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, this was already suggested, then rejected, and *then* lambdas were added in, so it very nearly made it in but happened not to, and is very likely to make it into the language in the future.

Comment: Any reference to the historic discussion would be great.  Any idea where to find some archives?