# Using auto in a lambda function

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, lambda

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

void foo( int )
{
}

int main()
{
  std::vector< int > v( { 1,2,3 } );

  std::for_each( v.begin(), v.end(), []( auto it ) { foo( it+5 ); } );
}
```

When compiled, the example above starts the error output like this :

```
h4.cpp: In function 'int main()':
h4.cpp:13:47: error: parameter declared 'auto'
h4.cpp: In lambda function:
h4.cpp:13:59: error: 'it' was not declared in this scope
```

Does it mean that the keyword `auto` should not be used in lambda expressions?

This works :

```
std::for_each( v.begin(), v.end(), []( int it ) { foo( it+5 ); } );
```

Why the version with the auto keyword doesn't work?

Comment: I think that even if it is a lambda, it still work as a function, and must have a signature. With auto you let the compiler decide of the type, so your lambda has no real signature until compile-time.

Comment: We really need polymorphic lambdas (AKA implicit templates) in the next standard.  This question is just one of several instances where people just assume `auto` works this way.  I see no reason it shouldn't.

Comment: deft_code , I'm with you. It is a logical usage case for auto.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

auto keyword does not work as a type for function arguments, in C++11. If you don't want to use the actual type in lambda functions, then you could use the code below.

```
 for_each(begin(v), end(v), [](decltype(*begin(v)) it ){
       foo( it + 5);         
 });
```

The code in the question works just fine in C++ 14.

Comment: We're going to get `auto` support in lambdas in [C++14](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14#Generic_lambdas).

Comment: Mind the star before the `begin(v)` in `decltype`. You want the value type not the iterator type. (error messages when you fail that will be mysterious).

Answer (score 24):

C++14 allows lambda function (Generic lambda function) parameters to be declared with the auto.

```
auto multiply = [](auto a, auto b) {return a*b;};
```

For details: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

Answer (score 22):

This was discussed briefly by Herb Sutter during an interview. Your demand for `auto` arguments is in fact no different from demanding that *any* function should be declarable with `auto`, like this:

```
auto add(auto a, auto b) -> decltype(a + b) { return a + b; }
```

However, note that this isn't really a function at all, but rather it's a *template* function, akin to:

```
template <typename S, typename T>
auto add(S a, T b) -> decltype(a + b) { return a + b; }
```

So you are essentially asking for a facility to turn any function into a template by changing its arguments. Since templates are a very different sort of entity in the type system of C++ (think of all the special rules for templates, like two-phase look-up and deduction), this would be radical design change with unforeseeable ramifications, which certainly isn't going to be in the standard any time soon.

Comment: No, not asking or demanding :) I was just wondering why it doesn't work.

Comment: Well, it's essentially the same reason as for "why aren't all functions templates" -- it just doesn't fit into the design of the language.

Answer (score 4):

The type of the lambda needs to be known before the compiler can even instantiate `std::for_each`. On the other hand, even if it were theoretically possible, that `auto` could only be deduced after `for_each` has been instantiated by seeing how the functor is invoked.

If at all possible, forget about `for_each`, and use range-based for loops which are a lot simpler:

```
for (int it : v) { 
   foo(it + 5); 
}
```

This should also cope nicely with `auto` (and `auto&` and `const auto&`).

```
for (auto it : v) { 
   foo(it + 5); 
}
```

Comment: Yes but that only works with for_each, and not other algorithms. e.g. you want to sort on a lambda.