# C++ Having two "processes" run at the same time

Tags: c++

In a command line application I'm building I'd like to have two "processes" running at the same time. By processes, I mean such as:

Every 57 seconds, I would like to do task A, and every 250 seconds do task B. Those are arbitrarily chosen numbers, but you get the point.

How can I have both of these "processes" being checked at the same time?

Thanks guys

Comment: what's stopping you from using threads & sleeps?

Comment: What's a thread? As for sleeps, if I were to do a 57000 sleep, and then a 250000 sleep, the 57 second task would be skipped.

Comment: What operating system are you using

Comment: btw you can also use std::thread (C++11) regardless of the OS

Comment: why not set a `cron` job rather than adding the complexity in the code?

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this, if neither of the process takes long.

```
float Atime = 57.f;
float Btime = 250.f;
float startTime = someTimerFunc();
while(true) {
    sleep(a few milliseconds);


    float endTime = someTimerFunc();
    float deltaTime = endTime - startTime;
    startTime = endTime;



    Atime -= deltaTime;
    Btime -= deltaTime;
    if(Atime < 0) {
        Atime += 57.f;
        AProcess();
    }
    if(Btime < 0) {
        Btime += 250.f;
        BProcess();
    }
}
```

Or you could look up what threads do.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you very much! I'll try this out.

Comment: @JoshBeckwith I hope it helps. It might not work, I didn't test it but you can try it.

Answer (score 2):

Running 2 threads would be a good way to handle this unless you have a reason to *need* different processes. Something like this:

```
void taskA() { /*...*/ }
void taskB() { /*...*/ }

/*...*/

bool exit = false;
std::mutex mutex;
std::condition_variable cv;

auto runLoop = [&](auto duration, auto task)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{mutex};

        while(true)
        {
            if(!cv.wait_for(lock, duration, [&]{ return !exit; }))
                task();
            else
                return;
        }
    };

std::thread a{ [&]{ runLoop(std::chrono::seconds{57}, taskA); }};
std::thread b{ [&]{ runLoop(std::chrono::seconds{250}, taskB); }};
```

Doing it this way is cross platform standard C++, which is a major benefit. It uses C++11: lambdas and threading library.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709894/using-auto-in-a-lambda-function

Comment: @amdn ya... c++14 only.

Answer (score 1):

As said above, you can use threads instead of processes. If you are using c++11, have a look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/) on how you can create a thread.

In the example of the link, just replace foo and bar with the code that you want task A and task B to execute.

Also you can have a look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/this_thread/sleep_for/) for how you can make your program wait for some time with sleep.