# variadic templates with template function names and passing arguments and return values around

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

following from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39558976/variadic-templates-with-template-function-names/39570187?noredirect=1#comment66603297_39570187) question, I have been trying to create a template function that calls all same-named methods of its mixins. This has been done and verified in the previous question.

Now I am attempting to get the return value of SensorType::

Analytically:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>

struct EdgeSensor
{
    void update(int i) { std::cout << "EdgeSensor::update " << i <<  std::endl; }
    void updat2(const int i ) { std::cout << "EdgeSensor::updat2" << i << std::endl; }
    std::string printStats() { std::cout << "EdgeSensor::printStats" << std::endl; 
                               return std::string("EdgeSensor::printStats"); }
};

struct TrendSensor
{
    void update(int i ) { std::cout << "TrendSensor::update" << i << std::endl; }
    void updat2(const int i ) { std::cout << "TrendSensor::updat2" << i << std::endl; }
    std::string printStats() { std::cout << "TrendSensor::printStats" << std::endl; 
                               return std::string("TrendSensor::printStats"); }
};

template <class T, void (T::*)(const int)>
struct Method { };

template<typename ... SensorType>
class BaseSensor : public SensorType ... //to my BaseSensor class
{
   template <class T, void(T::*M)(const int)>
   int runSingle(Method<T, M> , const int i) {
      (this->*M)(i);
      return 0;
   }

   template <class... Ts>
   void runAll(const int i) {
      int run[sizeof...(Ts)] = { runSingle(Ts{},i)... };
      (void)run;
   }

public:
    void update() {
       runAll<Method<SensorType, &SensorType::update>...>(2);
    }
    void updat2() {
       const int k = 3;
       runAll<Method<SensorType, &SensorType::updat2>...>(k);
    }
    void printStats() {
    //   runAll<Method<SensorType, &SensorType::printStats>...>();
    }
};

int main() {
  {
    BaseSensor<EdgeSensor,TrendSensor> ets;
    ets.update();
    ets.updat2();
    ets.printStats();
  }

  {
    BaseSensor<EdgeSensor> ets;
    ets.update();
    ets.updat2();
    ets.printStats();
  }
}
```

The above compiles and runs fine. The problem is: how can I gather the return values (std::strings) from running the mixin `SensorType::printStats()` methods in `BaseSensor::printStats()` ?

If I try to create a 2ndary version of the `run*` functions and the `Method` template, I fail to make it compile. Say I did:

```
template <class T, void (T::*)()>
struct Method2 { };

template <class T, void(T::*M)()>
int runSingle2(Method2<T, M>) {
    (this->*M)();
    return 0;
}

template <class... Ts>
void runAll2() {
    std::string s;
    int run[sizeof...(Ts)] = { s = runSingle2(Ts{})... };
    (void)run;
    std::cout << "s=" << s << std::endl;
}

public:
    void update() {
        int k = 4;
        runAll<Method<SensorType, &SensorType::update>...>(k);
    }
    void printStats() {
        runAll2<Method2<SensorType, &SensorType::printStats>...>();
    }
};
```

This does not compile saying

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -g -std=c++11   -c -o "obj_dbg/main.opp" "main.cpp"
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void BaseSensor<SensorType>::printStats() [with SensorType = EdgeSensor, TrendSensor]’:
main.cpp:65:20:   required from here
main.cpp:58:8: error: could not convert template argument ‘&EdgeSensor::printStats’ to ‘void (EdgeSensor::*)()’
make: *** [obj_dbg/main.opp] Error 1
```

So HOW can I grab the return values from `SensorType::printStats()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you can use c++11, if so, then I think this is the easiest?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct EdgeSensor
{
    void update(int i) { std::cout << "EdgeSensor::update " << i <<  std::endl; }
    void updat2(const int i ) { std::cout << "EdgeSensor::updat2" << i << std::endl; }
    std::string printStats() { std::cout << "EdgeSensor::printStats" << std::endl; 
                               return std::string("EdgeSensor::printStats"); }
};

struct TrendSensor
{
    void update(int i ) { std::cout << "TrendSensor::update" << i << std::endl; }
    void updat2(const int i ) { std::cout << "TrendSensor::updat2" << i << std::endl; }
    std::string printStats() { std::cout << "TrendSensor::printStats" << std::endl; 
                               return std::string("TrendSensor::printStats"); }
};

template<typename ... SensorType>
class BaseSensor : public SensorType ... //to my BaseSensor class
{
public:
    void update() {
       auto v = { (static_cast<SensorType*>(this)->update(1), 0)... }; // *
       (void) v;
    }
    void updat2() {
       const int k = 3;
       auto v = { (static_cast<SensorType*>(this)->updat2(k), 0)... }; // *
       (void) v;
    }
    void printStats() {
       auto v = { static_cast<SensorType*>(this)->printStats()... };
       for (auto s : v) {
           std::cout << s << std::endl;
       }
    }
};

int main() {
  {
    BaseSensor<EdgeSensor,TrendSensor> ets;
    ets.update();
    ets.updat2();
    ets.printStats();
  }

  {
    BaseSensor<EdgeSensor> ets;
    ets.update();
    ets.updat2();
    ets.printStats();
  }
}
```

- NOTE: I am using a gcc extension here, but I think you are using gcc, so it should be okay

Comment: Nice!! gcc extension is inferring array type right?

Comment: `auto v = { (this->SensorType::update(1), 0)... };` could be even nicer (allows to avoid possible virtual dispatch error, which can't be done in the member pointer approach)

Comment: @W.F. no, that's part of the standard, however what is not is the usage of the `,` operator here, it's a GCC extension to mean apply expression before the `,`, discard the result, and then apply the expression after the `,` and use it's value. Hence, you have an initializer list with N 0s,

Answer (score 2):

Here is you code reviewed so as it works as requested:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct EdgeSensor
{
    void update(int i) { std::cout << "EdgeSensor::update " << i <<  std::endl; }
    void updat2(const int i ) { std::cout << "EdgeSensor::updat2" << i << std::endl; }
    std::string printStats() { std::cout << "EdgeSensor::printStats" << std::endl; 
    return std::string("EdgeSensor::printStats"); }
};

struct TrendSensor
{
    void update(int i ) { std::cout << "TrendSensor::update" << i << std::endl; }
    void updat2(const int i ) { std::cout << "TrendSensor::updat2" << i << std::endl; }
    std::string printStats() { std::cout << "TrendSensor::printStats" << std::endl; 
    return std::string("TrendSensor::printStats"); }
};

template<typename ... SensorType>
class BaseSensor : public SensorType ... {
    template<typename F>
    struct Invoke;

    template<typename R, typename... A>
    struct Invoke<R(A...)> {
        template <R(SensorType::* ...M)(A...), typename T>
        static std::vector<R> run(T *t, A... args) {
            std::vector<R> vec;
            int arr[] = { (vec.push_back((t->*M)(args...)), 0)... };
            (void)arr;  
            return vec;
        }
    };

    template<typename... A>
    struct Invoke<void(A...)> {
        template <void(SensorType::* ...M)(A...), typename T>
        static void run(T *t, A... args) {
            int arr[] = { ((t->*M)(args...), 0)... };
            (void)arr;  
        }
    };

public:
    void update() {
       Invoke<void(int)>::template run<&SensorType::update...>(this, 2);
    }
    void updat2() {
       const int k = 3;
       Invoke<void(int)>::template run<&SensorType::updat2...>(this, k);
    }
    void printStats() {
         auto vec = Invoke<std::string(void)>::template run<&SensorType::printStats...>(this);
         for(auto &&v: vec) {
             std::cout << "--->" << v << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

int main() {
  {
    BaseSensor<EdgeSensor,TrendSensor> ets;
    ets.update();
    ets.updat2();
    ets.printStats();
  }

  {
    BaseSensor<EdgeSensor> ets;
    ets.update();
    ets.updat2();
    ets.printStats();
  }
}
```

I refactored a bit the code, for there was no need for the `Method` class. This works as intended and the strings returned by the `printStats` methods are now collected in a `std::vector` and returned to the caller.

Comment: Hi there, unfortunately the above does not compile https://godbolt.org/g/tJMtiZ . I have been trying to figure out why, but perhaps you can identify it more easily

Comment: @nass It compiles with [clang](https://godbolt.org/g/Nm8maE), but it doesn't with GCC. I created a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39665300/gcc-vs-clang-variadic-template-and-pointers-to-member-methods) to explore if it's a problem of GCC or of the code, but no answers yet unfortunately. I'll be back as far as I have some news for you.

Comment: ah yes indeed I saw that and been following it :) Perhaps it would be useful to add this info as part of the answer (at least until a solution is provided)

Comment: @nass Quite interesting an error, I would be tempted to say that the code is correct, but I'm not sure 100% that the expansion is valid. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

To extend the solution to any type of member function you could do (and actually a bit simplify it still having in mind c++11 restriction). The approach resolves type of member function to be able to infer its result type. It also uses `InferOwnerType` to infer mixin type and avoid direct passing of statically casted `this` pointer. Depending on the result of the member function now we can store it into an array or use the trick with `int` array just to be sure each member function is invoked.

```
#include <iostream> // std::cout std::endl
#include <string>   // std::string
#include <utility>  // std::declval

struct EdgeSensor //a mixin
{
    void update(int a){ std::cout << "EdgeSensor::update" << a << std::endl; }
    std::string updat2(int const v) { return "EdgeSensor::printStats"; }
};

struct TrendSensor //another mixin
{
    void update(int a){ std::cout << "TrendSensor::update" << std::endl; }
    std::string updat2(int const v) { return "TrendSensor::printStats"; }
};

template <class Res, class This, class... Args>
This InferOwnerType(Res (This::*foo)(Args...)) { }

template<typename ... SensorType>
class BaseSensor : public SensorType ... //to my BaseSensor class
{
    template <class M, class... Args>
    auto run(M m, Args... args)
       -> decltype((std::declval<decltype(InferOwnerType(m))*>()->*m)(args...)) {
       return (static_cast<decltype(InferOwnerType(m))*>(this)->*m)(args...);
    }

public:
    template <class... Args>
    void update(Args... args) {
       int arr[] = {(run(&SensorType::update, args...), 0)...};
       (void)arr;
    }
    template <class... Args>
    void updat2(Args... args) {
       std::string s[] = {run(&SensorType::updat2, args...)...};
       for (int i = 0; i < sizeof...(SensorType); i++)
          std::cout << s[i] << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
   BaseSensor<EdgeSensor, TrendSensor> bs;
   bs.update(4);
   bs.updat2(0);
   BaseSensor<EdgeSensor> bs2;
   bs2.update(1);
   bs2.updat2(0);
}
```

Comment: Hi there, once again , in trying to understand what is going on, I have a few questions :) can we talk about them in a chat window?

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123992/discussion-between-nass-and-w-f

Comment: The `InferThisType` is somehow crazy, but intriguing too. :-D

Comment: @skypjack Right wording isnt very good maybe `InferOwnerClass` was a better choice...

Comment: @skypjack I read your comment in a way and I believe I reinterpret it a bit... you meant treating the member pointer as a say tag to be dispatched is somewhat crazy :) well I admit I'm a bit crazy guy (~o~)