# GCC vs clang: variadic template and pointers to member methods

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang, language-lawyer

Consider the following code:

```
struct S { void f() { } };
struct T { void f() { } };

template<typename... M>
struct U: M... {
    template<void(M::*... F)(void)>
    void g() { }

    void f() {
        g<&M::f...>();
    }
};

int main() {
    U<S, T> u;
    u.f();
}
```

This is a minimal example, of course.
The intent is to forward internally a bunch of pointers to member methods as a template parameter of a function that executes them by unpacking the list.
It works with [clang v3.9](https://godbolt.org/g/agQtbY), it doesn't compile with [GCC v6.2](https://godbolt.org/g/4oBzET).

Here is the error returned by GCC:

```
/tmp/gcc-explorer-compiler116823-58-9skgit/example.cpp: In instantiation of 'void U<M>::f() [with M = {S, T}]':
16 : required from here
10 : error: no matching function for call to 'U<S, T>::g()'
g<&M::f...>();
~~~~~~~~~~~^~
7 : note: candidate: template<void (M::* ...F)()> void U<M>::g() [with void (M::* ...F)() = {F ...}; M = {S, T}]
void g() { }
^
7 : note: template argument deduction/substitution failed:
10 : error: wrong number of template arguments (2, should be 1)
g<&M::f...>();
~~~~~~~~~~~^~
Compilation failed
```

Which compiler is right? Is this ill-formed code or not?

Comment: Both compilers produce an error... Even though error messages differ, which is to be expected... they appear to agree, right?

Comment: @BitTickler [clang](https://godbolt.org/g/agQtbY) does not produce errors (at least, v3.9).

Comment: Was not aware that gcc changed its compiler output style to wigglies ;) Sorry.